# Kubernetes Service account authentication in Postman

Tags: kubernetes, postman, service-accounts, jwt

I have a kubernetes cluster and i have my application deployed in the pods. There is a endpoint URL of my application which i used to send POST requests from Postman. I need to provide some level of authentication to the my URL. I read the service account authentication using the JWT token.

How can i achieve the same feature in postman ??

I tried creating a new service account and took the secret and the associated JWT token as the Bearer token in postman. But it is not giving any kind of authentication.

https://medium.com/better-programming/k8s-tips-using-a-serviceaccount-801c433d0023

Answer (score 0):

Cant directly answer your question, but from what comes to my mind is that: **[Istio](https://istio.io/) supports Token-based end-user authentication with JSON Web  Tokens.**

You should understand I havent tried to do that, but this looks for me very promising: [Istio End-User Authentication for Kubernetes using JSON Web Tokens (JWT) and Auth0](https://itnext.io/securing-kubernetes-withistio-end-user-authentication-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-97f4bb8e71c6)

And to test JWT-based authentication and authorization workflow thay exactly use Postman, as you prefer.

Comment: Actually kubernetes dashboard  GUI have an authentication regarding service account JWT token, it will ask for a token and I have to give that to reach the main console. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml` .I am trying to enable the same for a URL end point also.

Comment: I created a serviceaccount, binded it with cluster-admin(to get all privileges) and added that serviceaccount in the deployment file,